# Repeating a QFormLayout multiple times in the same QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm using PyQt4 with Python 3.5 to make a simple application and I'm running into a wall.

I have a Qwidget as setCentralWidget, and in is  make a QFormLayout

```
    flo = QtGui.QFormLayout() 
    flo.addRow("input 1", QtGui.QLineEdit)
    flo.addRow("input 2", QtGui.QLineEdit)
```

Now, I want this QFormLayout to be repeated as many times as the user desires in the same window, as to give him/her the opportunity to insert multiple inputs. But iI can't figure out to do this.

I've tried it with for-loops, or with different layouts, but it either simply doesn't seem to work, or the QlineEdit is only intractable for the last created instance, while the strings are displayed 'properly'.

What is a correct method do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `{your QFormLayout}.addRow({string}, QtGui.QLineEdit)` to `{your QFormLayout}.addRow({string}, QtGui.QLineEdit())`

Example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("<center>Ejemplo</center>")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.formLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout)
        self.lineEdits = []
        for i in range(10):
            lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
            self.formLayout.addRow(str(i), lineEdit)
            self.lineEdits.append(lineEdit)

        self.lineEdits[2].setText("a")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works, but it raised another problem. How can i access the data from the QLineEdit()? Normally I would do it like this: variable = QtGui.QLineEdit(), and then i can access the data by variable.text, but now i wouldn't know how to access the data.

Comment: To specify; is there a possibility to access the data without first initializing the variables?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen  update my solution: self.lineEdits[{position}].{function}

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!